# How to replace JSON array value withe new one using Angular.js/javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I need to replace JSON array value using Angular.js/Javascript. this is my code below.

Suppose i pushed some value to an object like below.

```
for(var i=0;i<mondayarr.length;i++){
    $scope.days[0].answers.push({
                category:{'value':mondayarr[i].cat_id},
                subcategory: null,
                comment: response.data[i].comment,
  })
  $scope.setSubcatag(0);
}
```

inside the loop i pushed some value into the array and called a function with the value. this is the `subcategory` is assigned to null.

```
$scope.setSubcatag=function(index){
   $scope.days[index].answers.push({
            subcategory:{'value':2}
  })
}
```

In the above section i am replacing `subcategory` value null to some value but its not replacing. please help me.

Comment: You are trying to push another object into the array.

Comment: what is the `subcat_id` your are refer to in the `setSubcatag`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are pushing a new object to the `days[index].answer` where you should assign the subcategory. in order to do so you need to add a new argument to the setSubcatag.

```
$scope.setSubcatag=function(index,answerId)
{
   $scope.days[index].answers[answerId].subcategory = {'value':2};
}
```

and in the base

```
for(var i=0;i<mondayarr.length;i++){
    $scope.days[0].answers.push({
                category:{'value':mondayarr[i].cat_id},
                subcategory: null,
                comment: response.data[i].comment,
  })
  $scope.setSubcatag(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing one more value to the array, instead replace it, but you have to know the answer's index as well.

```js
$scope.setSubcatag=function(index)
{
   $scope.days[index].answers[whichAnswerIndex].subcategory = {'value':subcat_id};
}
```